# Access Default Printer only accepts manual paper feed

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, printers

We have a HP LaserJet 6P on our POS set as the default printer with auto select as the paper source and this VBA code to print:

```
Dim stDocName As String
Me.Refresh
stDocName = "Retail Receipt"
Dim prtr As Access.Printer
Set Application.Printer = Nothing
Set prtr = Application.Printer
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acNormal
```

However it will only print if there is paper in the manual feed tray I have tried setting it for this and that and if I try from notepad it prints fine so it must be something in access that isn't allowing it to print

anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Is the print function just to print a report directly? If so, you can try this behind a button click:

```
    Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Retail Receipt", acViewNormal, "", "", acNormal
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint
    Exit Sub
```

It should take the default printer settings to print directly.

Comment: it is but we want it to go straight to the printer it works in the backend with the other printers in the offices

Comment: Try opening the report in Print Preview **without** using any VBA, then from there use the system print dialogue to select the printer you want to use. Print a copy, save your work, exit the app, then open it up again and try to print via the VBA code I provided.

Access likes to make its own defaults for printing (thus the error some reports get when being printed from a different PC with different printers installed -- "This report was originally formatted for XXX printer. It will be printed using your default settings.")

Comment: Tried that I also tried setting the default tray on the printer to tray 2 and printing and it's erroring out on tray 1 even though its set to only print from tray 2